# What does CDK-compatible mean?

Tags: aws-cdk

In the [CONTRIBUTING](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) guide, there is a section on Docker that says:

> This allows you to run the CDK in a CDK-compatible directory with a command like:

What does "CDK-compatible" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

In this context `CDK-compatible` means *containing a valid CDK project* with a `cdk.json`.

Comment: This would imply that I cannot run `cdk init ....` from the container because that command can only be run from an empty directory. Is this accurate?